# ASP.NET Core - Can UseSession() be used before UseAuthentication() and UseAuthorization()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I'm working on an ASP.NET code base that uses sessions, authentication, and authorization.

They are initialized in the following order:

```cs
app.UseSession();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

The [Middleware Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#middleware-order) documentation shows `app.UseSession()` *after* the other two, but the documentation later says:

> Session Middleware (UseSession) establishes and maintains session state. If the app uses session state, **call Session Middleware after Cookie Policy Middleware and before MVC Middleware.**

*Emphasis mine.*

Our app uses custom authentication code to handle different flows, and one of these initializes some data inside of sessions.

Because of this, placing the `app.UseSession()` method *after* the authentication/authorization middleware causes the app to crash when that flow is triggered.

Is is safe to leave `app.UseSession()` before the other two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `UseAuthentication` nor `UseAuthorization` are the Cookie Policy Middleware which is added for example by `UseCookiePolicy` (see [EU General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR) support in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/gdpr?view=aspnetcore-7.0)).

The [Session and state management in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-7.0) doc mentions the following about the order:

> The order of middleware is important. Call `UseSession` after `UseRouting` and before `MapRazorPages` and `MapDefaultControllerRoute`. See [Middleware Ordering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#order).

The ordering doc you have already linked and the only additional order description I found there applicable to the situation is the following:

> `UseCors`, `UseAuthentication`, and `UseAuthorization` must appear in the order shown.

Based on the docs and quick code peek into the session middleware it should be ok to use it before the auth ones:

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseSession();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: For some reason I thought the `UseCookiePolicy()` middleware was related to authentication policies, and I knew `UseAuthentication` or `UseAuthorization` did stuff with cookies, so I wasn't sure.